# Regular expression using unicode flag failing in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, python-re

I want to use the regular expression `[^\p{L}0-9]/u`, but it is failing in IE and FF because these browsers do not support the features introduced in ECMAScript 2018 standard yet.

I want a workaround so that I can use the unicode flag `/u`.

Comment: Chrome 68+ should support /u

Comment: I get no errors for `const re = new RegExp("[^\p{L}0-9]/u","g")` in Chrome